# Should I inform the copyright holder that I plan to invoke the fair use doctrine if they decide to pursue legal action against me?

Tags: united-states, fair-use, data-ownership, research

### **Context/Background:**

I'm currently trying to navigate the legal intricacies of using content from a company whose platform revolves around athletic/sports data. For anyone who might be familiar, this company is a large social network (based in the United States) with millions of users who post their workouts and athletic activities online for others to see. It is essentially a social network for runners/cyclists/athletes, and the posted content consists of activities uploaded and shared by these users.

I am an academic researcher with an interest in sports statistics. While reviewing the content on this social media platform, I discovered some interesting results that I'd like to turn into an academic/journal publication. Essentially, I performed some statistical analysis on some of the platform's data (which is visible and accessible by anyone with an account on the platform) and came to some meaningful conclusions, which I'd now like to publish as a paper.

Obviously, there are legal considerations to be made before trying to publish these results.

Above all, the company has a Terms of Service that I agreed to in order to use the platform. The Terms of Service explicitly state that I may not "create derivative works from the content of the service". This is a significant obstacle that would prevent me from achieving my goal of publishing my results.

I reached out to the legal team at this company asking for an exemption to this clause for the purpose of my academic research. In return, I received a fairly generic response that all users of the platform are bound to the Terms of Service and must abide by them (which is fair, but already known). I have since followed up with the company to explain my objectives in more detail; I am currently awaiting a response to my e-mail.

In the meanwhile, I was considering other approaches to publishing this work and did some research into how fair use doctrine might support my case here. I think there are a few points that I have in my favor here:

1. The purpose and nature of the use is for noncommercial, nonprofit educational purposes. Specifically, the nature of the use is for research and scholarship.
2. The nature of the use is fairly *transformative*, as I would be publishing the analyzed/summarized statistical data and not any of the raw content from the platform.
3. To some extent, I guess that you could say the raw data represents facts, which are not protected by copyright laws.
4. The appropriate attribution and acknowledgment would be provided to the company regarding the use of their data in the publication.
5. Finally, I would not be harming the copyright owner's market or limiting their ability to exploit the original data for their own purposes.

These are all points that I could pitch to support my argument. I'm not sure if the fair use doctrine would, in this case, supersede the relevance of the company's Terms of Service. For the purpose of this question, let's assume that the argument I've posed above is reasonable (although please feel free to leave a comment if there are notable flaws in my reasoning).

### **Question:**

*Should I inform the copyright holder (i.e. the company and its legal team) that I would intend to invoke the fair use doctrine if they were to pursue legal action against me?*

If so, to what extent should I detail my argument—should I simply let them know that I would invoke fair use in my defense, or should I go even further and explain my arguments for each of the four factors for fair use consideration?

If not, what is the reason for withholding my intentions from the company?

On one hand, I believe that expressing my intent to invoke fair use might make them concede to my request (both because it may be perceived as grounded in legal doctrine *and* because they'll realize that I am not willing to back down without a fight). On the other hand, I worry that giving them too much information upfront might end up working against me if I end up in a legal battle against the company (which is not something I want to do unless there's a very strong chance that I'd win).

How should I play my cards here? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each option?

Comment: My first question would be whether and to what extent the data even enjoys copyright protection.  I suppose that data about a person's athletic activities may not be a "literary work," even under the very broad definition of that term pertaining in US law.  Furthermore, copyright in content comprising "activities uploaded and shared by these users" would originate with the users, not the platform, so the answer to that question depends a bit on the license agreement, if any, under which those users share their content.

Comment: @phoog That's a great question which, unfortunately, I don't know the answer to. If the data DON'T enjoy copyright protection, does that mean that a theoretical legal battle with this company would essentially fall back to being about their Terms of Service?

Comment: I suppose so.  That would presumably also be the case if the data does enjoy copyright protection and your use is allowable as fair use.  I expect that someone else more knowledgeable about these things than am I will answer or comment.

Comment: Please note that this site can't offer you legal advice or evaluate for you the legal risks of your options.  That is something that you should do with your institution's legal team (I assume you work for a university or similar institution).  If the company disagrees with whatever you do, they may very well sue your university instead of (or in addition to) you personally.  That is not great for your career.

Comment: One concern is that AFAIK, fair use is only a defense to *copyright infringement*.  The TOS, on the other hand, is a contract, and there's no fair use defense to breach of contract.  It is perfectly possible to agree in a contract not to do something that copyright law would otherwise permit, and such a contract would be binding AFAIK.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your input! I definitely don't intend to rely on the internet's advice to fight this battle--just wanted to assess what my options are and see if there's a sense in my thoughts before I get too deep into this. I think your note that 'fair use is only a defense to copyright infringement' might be something I need to look into further with a legal counsel. I get the feeling that my success or failure might hinge heavily on that argument...

Comment: @NateEldredge Am I wrong in thinking that TOS is a contract which allows access to content that is not available under fair use though.  Access to the content is the only consideration you get in exchange for the TOS' restrictions, is it not?

Comment: @grovkin: Copyright and fair use have to do with conditions under which you can *copy* the content or create derivative works of it.  But that's all moot unless you can  get access to the content in the first place, and I don't see why the company can't require you to waive some rights in exchange for allowing said access.

Comment: @NateEldredge that's method of delivery vs content itself (TOS on the library card vs TOS on reading a book in the library).  Even if you agree not to take notes while reading a book inside the library in exchange for entering the library, the only penalty that can be levied against you is the one you agree to prior to entering the library.  Your taking the notes doesn't *automatically* annul your agreement under TOS (and make your presence a form trespassing), unless you agreed that it would annul the agreement, but it does constitute a breach.

Comment: @NateEldredge so while it maybe a violation of the TOS to do something with the content, it is not (in itself) a copyright violation.  In fact, if what you do with the content happens to be fair use, then you violate TOS of access without breaking the copyright law.  You can be banned for violating TOS.  Then you won't be able to have *further* access.  But it doesn't in itself make former access (allowed under TOS) a violation of the law... IMHO

Comment: @grovkin: In addition to being banned for violating the TOS, you could also be liable for damages, as for any breach of contract.  I do agree that if your use is fair use, you're not liable for copyright infringement at any point, regardless of what TOS says.  But getting your employer sued for breach of TOS can get you just as fired as for copyright infringement.

Answer (score 3):

We cannot dispense personalized legal advice: that is what your attorney is for. However, I agree with your analysis that this is most likely covered by fair use, and indeed it is not obvious that you have taken anything that is protected. There is no creativity behind a number such as entries in the "I did N pushups" column. The arrangement of data into a web page passes the smidgen of creativity test, but "210" is not a creative number.

The terms of service of a website cannot negate your right to use the website however you want in a non-infringing way. If your use is "fair use", then they can't tell you that you can't use it. In case it turns out that "fair use" fails, the matter would hinge on what exactly the TOS says. They may have granted you permission to make use of their "information". So there are three positive avenues for you to consider: not protected, fair use, and permitted.

A practical difficulty is that a university lawyer is only interested in the interests of the university, and they are as likely to say "don't do that" or "get permission" as they are to say "that is fair use". You can hire a lawyer who is paid to care about *your* interest, though there is never a guarantee that the lawyer's advice is correct. I think it is likely that the lawyer will tell you to not say anything until legally forced to, given the apparent rebuff of your request for special permission.

Comment: "The terms of service of a website cannot negate your right to use the website however you want in a non-infringing way": why not?

Comment: @phoog if you legally don't need a license to access the content, then no one can legally restrict that type of access.  This seems more like semantics than law.

Comment: @grovkin then what is the purpose of terms of service?

Comment: @phoog to outline restrictions to which you must agree in exchange for the consideration of having access to content which *does* need licensing.

Comment: @grovkin no, it's to outline restrictions to which I must agree in exchange for the consideration of being allowed to use the service through which the content is being made available.  If I violate the terms of service, I can be banned from the platform.  My so-called right to have access to the content does not prevent this.

Comment: @phoog that's a separate consideration.  you are talking about the TOS on method of delivery of content.  Which is not the same as the consideration of having the right to view the content.

Comment: What @grovkin said.

Comment: I think maybe we're disagreeing over the word "use".  I agree that the TOS cannot make you liable for copyright infringement for use that would otherwise be fair use.  But copyright infringement isn't the only way for them to get you.  If such use is itself a violation of the TOS, then you're liable for violating the TOS, and for any damages that may result.

Comment: What is the consideration offered to the user that makes a TOS binding?

Comment: @user6726 access to the site is consideration.

Comment: Uh, no, permission is consideration. Next question: permission to do what?

Comment: @user6726: Permission to see and download the data on the site.

Comment: Which is why the TOS is relevant to actions where permission is statutorily required, but not w.r.t. things not protected by copyright law.

Comment: @NateEldredge If you've placed some information somewhere and made it accessible to everyone (i.e. no access controls, no login, etc.), then what legal basis do you have to tell someone that he can't read that information without accepting a TOS first? It would be like placing a book in a bookstore and then printing on the first page, "license agreement for readers: you may not read the final chapter of this book unless you have first purchased the book."  So, if I am still in the bookstore and I flip ahead to the final chapter to see how it ends before buying it, am I breaking a law?

Comment: @Brandin: No.  The distinction is between *reading*, which is perfectly legal, and *copying*, which is not.  Retrieving data from a website creates a copy, even if only temporarily, which requires permission from the copyright holder.  Reading a book in a bookstore does not create a copy, and so you can read it as much as you want without infringing copyright.